# Intonation of questions in ancient Hebrew

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk, pronunciation

That is, when someone asks a question in English, their pitch goes up at the end.  When someone makes a statement in English, their pitch goes down.  This is not universal: In German, only [some questions](http://mendele.commons.yale.edu/wp/category/volume-06/volume-06-172/#question-intonation) are intoned like that.  In Chinese, questions have a gently rising tone throughout, and sentences go gently down.
Is there any evidence of the intonation patterns for Biblical (or Mishnaic or Talmudic) Hebrew?

Comment: I've closed this as off-topic, as it's about the Hebrew language and not about (or arising from) Jewish life or Jewish study. Please see the answer http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/164 and its comments for a detailed explanation.

Comment: That said, welcome to the site. I hope you stick around and enjoy it, and contribute topically. Might I suggest you [register](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your [account](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/u/1498)? Doing so will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Fascinating question, though!

Comment: I think you should repost the question here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36772/hebrew-language-usage. I doubt you'll get an answer any time in the near future, but there's always a chance and it would be much more on topic there.

Comment: Thanks, @Ari.  I think I might have found something like an answer on page 191 of [Semitic Languages: Outline of a Comparative Grammar, by Edward Lipiński, &copy; 2001](http://books.google.com/books?id=IiXVqyEkPKcC&lpg=PA108&vq=intonation&pg=PA191#v=onepage&q=question&f=false)

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Interesting idea (in that book). He only gives examples from Hebrew for declarative sentences. I think if you edit the question to seek different pausal patterns in Tanakh between declarative, interrogative, and exclamatory sentences it would be in scope again, and can help us better assess Pan Lipiński's theory.

Comment: @DoubleAA You mean trope indications?  As in munach vs. pashta?  I'm honestly not sure how to ask that!

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman I was thinking more along the lines of pausal vowel forms like yoch-LU vs yo-CHEI-lu or Eretz vs Aretz. If you don't mind I can try editing it; we won't re-open it without your permission.

Comment: @DoubleAA go for it :)

Comment: http://www.jamesdprice.com/images/Pausal_Forms_ETS_paper.pdf